# Using a custom filter in multiple controllers (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and trying to convert my existing site to utilize AngularJS components. I have a filter that shows me the top level of links to use for my navigation. I am using it in multiple controllers:

```
$scope.topLevelLinks = function(link) {
    if (link.parent_id == 0) {
        return link;
    }
};
```

When I add the code above to each controller, it does exactly what I'd like it to do, when I call it:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="link in links | filter: topLevelLinks">
```

However, I am trying to add it to my module so I don't have to write it in both controllers and I cannot seem to get it to work.  I don't get any errors, it just does not filter my links:

```
app.factory('NavigationService', ['$http', function($http) {

return {
    getLinks: function () {
        return $http({

            method: 'GET',
            url: '/navigation',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }
};

}]).filter('topLevelLinks', function() {

return function(link) {
    if (link.parent_id == 0) {
        return link;
    }
};

}).controller('NavigationCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'NavigationService', function ($scope, $http, $nav) {

$scope.links = [];

$nav.getLinks().success(function(data) {
    $scope.links = data;
});

$scope.hasChildren = function(link) {
    return link.children.length > 0;
};

}]).controller('NavigationAdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'NavigationService', function ($scope, $http, $nav) {

$scope.links = [];

$nav.getLinks().success(function(data) {
    $scope.links = data;
});

}]);
```

Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have above is not a filter, it is just a method on your controller.

To create a filter you can do this:

```
angular.module('moduleName').filter('topLevelLinks', function(input){
  var output = [];
  for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    if (input[i].parent_id == 0) {
        output.push(input[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
});
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="link in links | filter: topLevelLinks">
```

You can find more info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

Comment: Gotcha.  Like I said, I'm pretty new to this, so I didn't know.  What you posted makes sense, and I tried it... but, for some reason, it still doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Did you remove the function from your controller's scope?